# Remover código %20 de URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei uma pagina php e quando passo ele via GET para outra ,apresentando o sinal de + quando salvo em um cookie .Esse + é a codificação do código %20.Algum sabe como remover da url esse %20?

link: pagina.php?valor=%20meuvalor

trecho do codigo

```
        $('.grupos').click(function () {

            var valorGrup=  $(this).text();/pega o texto contido no elemento cuja classe é (.grupos)



            $('.grupos').attr('href','pagina.php? 
         nomeGrupo='+valorGrup);//adiciona um link na classa .grupos



        });
```

Comment: Na verdade, o caractere `%20` é um espaço em branco, então provavelmente `valorGrup` possui um espaço em branco no início.

Comment: Tente usando .trim(): `var valorGrup=  $(this).text().trim();`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vc estava certo.Usei uma expressão para remover os espaços em branco.E funcionou.O estranho é que estava gerando um sinal de +.Mas ja foi resolvido.Obrigado